# Autowired value in Class null

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have two classes

```
   @Component
   public class EventProcessor {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(EventProcessor.class);

    @Autowired
    private MyProperties myProperties;

    /**
     * Listens to the Event hub
     * 
     * @throws InterruptedException
     * @throws ExecutionException
     */
    public void startProcess() throws Exception {
        EventProcessorHost host = new EventProcessorHost(
                EventProcessorHost.createHostName(myProperties.getEventproperties().getHostNamePrefix(),
                myProperties.getEventproperties().getEventHubName(),
                myProperties.getEventproperties().getConsumerGroupName(),
                myProperties.getEventproperties().getEventHubConnectionString(),
                myProperties.getEventproperties().getStorageConnectionString(),
                myProperties.getEventproperties().getStorageContainerName());
        EventProcessorOptions options = new EventProcessorOptions();
        host.registerEventProcessor(AzureEventHubReceiver.class, options).get();

    }

}
```

and

```
    @Component
    public class AzureEventHubReceiver implements IAzureEventHubReceiver {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AzureEventHubReceiver.class);

    private int checkpointBatchingCount = 0;


    @Autowired
    private IDeployStatusService deployStatusService;


    @Override
    public void onOpen(PartitionContext context) throws Exception {

    }

    @Override
    public void onClose(PartitionContext context, CloseReason reason) throws Exception {

    }

    @Override
    public void onError(PartitionContext context, Throwable error) {

    }

    /* 
     * 
     */
    @Override
    public void onEvents(PartitionContext context, Iterable<EventData> events)
            throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException, JsonParseException, JsonMappingException, IOException {
        for (EventData data : events) {
            // Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
            ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
            // EventHubModel model = null;

            EventHubModel[] model = objectMapper.readValue(new String(data.getBytes(), "UTF8"), EventHubModel[].class);
            if(model!=null && deployStatusService!=null) {
            deployStatusService.saveOrUpdateToDb(model[0].getData().getCorrelationId(), model[0].getData().getStatus());
            } 
            this.checkpointBatchingCount++;
            if ((checkpointBatchingCount % 5) == 0) {
                context.checkpoint(data).get();
            }
        }

}}
```

The Event processor class gets loaded on springboot start up using commandLineRunner

```
    @Component
    public class EventProcessorRunner implements CommandLineRunner{
    @Autowired
    private  EventProcessor processor; 

    EventProcessorRunner(final EventProcessor processor) {
       this.processor = processor;
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        processor.startProcess();

    }

}
```

The IDeployStatus Interface is as below

```
    public interface IDeployStatusService {

    void saveCorrelationId(String correlationId,Long serviceId, Long userSubscriptionId, ProvisioningState provisioningState);

    void saveOrUpdateToDb(String correlationId, String status);
}
```

and the implementation is

```
 @Service
   public class DeployStatusService implements IDeployStatusService {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DeployStatusService.class);

    @Autowired
    IServiceConverter serviceConverter;

    @Autowired
    ServiceRepo serviceRepo;

    @Autowired
    IDeployConverter deployConverter;

    @Autowired
    ISubConverter subConverter;

    @Autowired
    SubRepository subRepo;

    @Autowired
    ServiceDeployRepository serviceDeployRepository;

    @Override
    public void saveCorrelationId(String correlationId, Long serviceId, Long userSubscriptionId,
            ProvisioningState provisioningState) {

    }
```

However the IDeployStatusService doesnt get initialized and always returns null even when an event is triggered from API and the control reaches here.Any idea as to what can be done?
I have tried to do constructor injection here on the deployStatusService but to no avail.

Comment: Do you have a valid `Bean` for implementation of `IDeployStatusService`?

Comment: of course.will post it here.Sorry i clearly missed that.

Comment: Is `host.registerEventProcessor` creating a `new DeployStatusService`? If so, then that instance isn't a Spring bean. Moving to constructor injection instead of field injection will help identify problems like this so.

Comment: host.registerEventProcessor(AzureEventHubReceiver.class, options).get(); registers this and that AzureEventHubReceiver class in turn has IDeployStatusService autowired.I tried constructor injection by giving public AzureEventHubReceiver(IDeployStatusService deployStatusService){this.deployStatusService=deployStatusService;.However i am still gettting it as null

Comment: using constructor injection i get the following error java.lang.InstantiationException: com.xxxx.service.impl.AzureEventHubReceiver           Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.xxxx.service.impl.AzureEventHubReceiver.<init>()

Comment: Take a look at [where should @Autowired be applied?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43174074/clean-code-where-should-autowired-be-applied).

Comment: Unfortunately this one by NIkolay doesnt help in this case.

Comment: @chrylis did that too but yet its null.Could it be something to do with the new in EventProcessor that Spring isnt able to manage the bean in AzureEventHubReceiver

Comment: @Codeip That exception tells you that someone (whoever is in charge of `registerEventProcessor`) is trying to create an instance of the class you're passing with a default constructor. Look up the documentation and see if you can pass in an instance instead of the class.